# haskel where clause not in scope error

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

Good day,

I am new to haskell and having a hell of a time trying to compile the following function definition in haskell

```
chaseFile :: [FilePath]          -- ^ path (directories to search)
          -> String              -- ^ base name
          -> [String]            -- ^ possible extensions
          -> IO String           -- ^ contents of file
chaseFile dirs basename exts
  = do results <- mapM tryReadFile fnames
       case dropWhile hasFailed results of
         ((Right (fc,fn)):_)
            -> errLn ("Read file: "++fn) >> return fc
         _  -> errLn ("Could not find file: "++basename) >> mzero
    where
      fnames = [d++'/':basename++'.':e | d <- dirs, e <- exts]
      hasFailed (Left _) = True
      hasFailed _        = False
      tryReadFile fn = try ( readFile fn >>= \fc -> return (fc,fn) )
```

the compiler gives the following error

```
*** Parser:
*** Renamer/typechecker:
..\contrib\StrategyLib-5.0\library\ChaseImports.hs:103:24:
 Not in scope: `try'
```

Thanks in anticipation

I added

```
import Control.Exception (try)
```

and I got the following compiler errors

```
*** Parser:
*** Renamer/typechecker:

..\contrib\StrategyLib-5.0\library\ChaseImports.hs:96:24:
No instance for (Exception t0) arising from a use of `tryReadFile'
The type variable `t0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Exception Data.Dynamic.Dynamic
    -- Defined in `Data.Dynamic'
  instance Exception ArithException -- Defined in `GHC.Exception'
  instance Exception ErrorCall -- Defined in `GHC.Exception'
  ...plus 8 others
In the first argument of `mapM', namely `tryReadFile'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: results <- mapM tryReadFile fnames
In the expression:
  do { results <- mapM tryReadFile fnames;
       case dropWhile hasFailed results of {
         ((Right (fc, fn)) : _) -> errLn ("Read file: " ++ fn) >> return fc
         _ -> errLn ("Could not find file: " ++ basename) >> mzero } }
```

The file is part of the XsdMetz project (svn checkout xsdmetz.googlecode.com/svn/trunk xsdmetz-read-only) written before 2010. Could it be that it is not haskel 2010 compliant?

Comment: Is this your real formatting or a copy-paste error?

Comment: I think it is copy and paste error. I will correct immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your error message `` Not in scope: `try' `` I'm guessing the layout discussion is all a misunderstanding, and you've rather forgot to import that function, which is not in the `Prelude`.  Put at the top of your file something like

```
import Control.Exception (try)
```

EDIT: It turns out that the code assumes the old Haskell 98 / Haskell 2010 semantics for `try`.  Unfortunately modern GHC has hidden that away in the `haskell98` and `haskell2010` packages.  It is *possible* you should use one of those anyway, if you need to compile the whole XsdMetz project. But otherwise, a simpler workaround is to do

```
import System.IO.Error (tryIOError)
```

and substitute `tryIOError` in your code instead of `try`.

Alternatively, you *can* use `Control.Exception.try`, but then you need to put a type annotation somewhere to restrict its highly overloaded type so it knows what type of exception to catch.

Comment: tanks for the reply. But I ended up with more errors. Kindly see the additional information I added to the post. The file is part of the XsdMetz project (svn checkout xsdmetz.googlecode.com/svn/trunk xsdmetz-read-only) which was written before 2010. Could be that it is not haskel 2010 compliant?

Comment: @Iktech Updated my answer, hopefully one of those methods should work. The project seems to have some modules named with Haskell 98 non-hierarchical names, although inconsistently.  Although with default flags, not even GHC is Haskell 2010 compliant on this issue :(

Comment: Thanks, the `tryIOError` suggestion worked. But there are still errors in other files of the project. Where can I download a haskel compiler that uses the haskel2010 libraries as the GHC 7.6 that I am using always reports module clashes between base and haskell2010 if I include the `-package haskell2010` flag

Comment: @Iktech [The GHC download page](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download) has a list. I don't know if those will contain all the modules you need. The project seems to use a mixture of non-hierarchical (`haskell98`) and hierarchical (`haskell2010`) module names. You might still be able to use a modern GHC with something like `-hide-package base -package haskell98 -package haskell2010` Although I'm slightly worried about clashes between the last two, or that you *need* something in modern `base` too.

Comment: @Iktech If you *still* get clashes, you may look into [package imports](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#package-imports).

Answer (score 3):

Layout failure.

Your where clause should be more indented than the function name.  (All the bindings in the where clause must have the same alignment; you did that.)

All the statements in the do should have the same alignment, and they should be indented more than the where.  ("results" and "case" should start on the same column.)

All the patterns in the case should have the same alignment, and they should be indented more than the do statements.  ("((Right" and "_" should start on the same column)

[Full layout rules](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-210002.7)

If you don't like the white-space sensitivity, you can (effectively) opt out of the layout rules by providing explicit braces and semicolons.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The actual layout of the code in the file I am trying to compile conforms to all the rules you pointed (I have edited the code in the post to reflect the actual layout in the file). Yet the error still persist. The file is part of the XsdMetz project (svn checkout http://xsdmetz.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ xsdmetz-read-only). I will glad if you can help me compile the project if it is not too much to ask.

Comment: lktech Now that you've corrected the layout of your post, and posted the actual error, you should find a solution in andwer posted by @Ørjan Johansen

Answer (score 2):

A where clause must be tabbed in one level from the name of the function.

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to modify the post. But the where clause was actually tabbed one level from the name of the function. It shares thesame tab level with the do clause

Comment: @Iktech And try indenting another level. I'm not 100% sure about the indentation rules.

Comment: thanks for your reply. The actual layout of the code in the file I am trying to compile conforms to all the rules you pointed (I have edited the code in the post to reflect the actual layout in the file). Yet the error still persist. The file is part of the XsdMetz project (svn checkout http://xsdmetz.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ xsdmetz-read-only). I will glad if you can help me compile the project if it is not too much to ask.